# Always align "Next badge" to the right, even when there are no badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, profile-page, badge-progress

A new user (unregistered) came by [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) a few minutes ago, and I looked at their activity page (for no real reason *shrug*) and saw this:

[image: badge demonstration]

As can be seen, the "next badge" is in the left side of that box, which is inconsistent with what users who already earned at least one badge see: (As they have the "newest" badge box)

[image]

As you can see, the "Next badge" box is aligned to the right

I think it's better to make it consistent and have the box always aligned to the right, even when there are no badges. One possible way is adding an element identical to the "next badge" box right before the existing one, and give it `opacity: 0;`.

Comment: That's not a bug, most likely a design choice to have the "next badge" box just stick to the left, no matter if there's other box or not. I'll edit this soon to focus on the actual request here (stick it to the right), if it is fine by you?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it is

Comment: This is done now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting. As Shadow Wizard noticed - this is not a bug, more a design choice. Since I don't have strong opinion which one makes more sense (aligned to right or left), I'll just give it a try and see what happens.

Anyway, it's waiting in repo for next build.

Comment: So if a counter feature request is posted which will get more than 2 upvotes (current score here), you will revert the change? Really a Game  of Votes! :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard we have monthly meeting when we flip a coin and decide if we keep fix/feature or revert it :)

Comment: Well all I thought was that it should probably have been consistent, so... yeah. But thanks :)